# Attempting to download an image in Blackberry Cascades QT, and QML

Tags: c++, qt, download, qml, blackberry-10

I am attempting to download images in Blackberry Cascades, C++, QT.

I am basically using code that looks like this:

```
void MyClass::download() {

    QUrl url(imagePath);
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    Q_ASSERT(connect(networkAccessManager_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(saveImage(QNetworkReply *))));

    networkAccessManager_->get(request);

}

void MyClass::saveImage(QNetworkReply *) {
    QByteArray imageData = reply->readAll();

    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "an error occured downloading the image";
        return;
    }

    qDebug() << imageData;
    //...
```

When I do this, the imageData just contains: "Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã, instead of the entire content of the image I downloaded.

Can someone explain this to me?, and how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think that the image is downloading.  I thought it was only a few bytes being downloaded, but actually it was more then just a few bytes - which is why no closing quote showed up when printing it out with qDebug, (the whole image goes on one line).

Answer (score 3):

Its in QByteArray form that's why it shows like that. Just pass it in constructor of Image's object like this:

```
Image image = Image(reply->readAll());
imageView->setImage(image);
```

It should work. If it doesn't, Image would be too large to fit in ImageView. Max dimensions of an image which can be handled by cascade ImageView is 2048. So you may have to use ImageData class to replicate large image into cascade ImageView.

Also try loading image from this [url](http://cdn3.berryreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/blackberry-10-dev-alpha.jpg)  It works for me with this [url](http://cdn3.berryreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/blackberry-10-dev-alpha.jpg) without any use of ImageData class

Comment: Thankyou, but I still get "Ã¿Ã˜Ã¿Ã for my byte array and when I try to put it into the Image, I get this compiler error message: error: no matching function for call to 'bb::cascades::Image::Image(QByteArray&)'

Comment: Okay, I guess you are working on beta 2 SDK. In that Image class doesn't have a constructor accepting QByteArray as parameter. So you have to create QImage using that QByteArray then have to manipulate that QImage using QPainter & PixelBufferData class.

I would strongly recommend you to switch to beta 3 SDK as soon as possible. I faced a lot many issues when I switched, as so many things were changed & my efforts were wasted. Even the PixelBufferData class has been deprecated & been replaced by ImageData class since beta 3.

Comment: If you still want to make it work for beta 2, you can take a look at this tutorial: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development-Knowledge/Using-QImage-and-QPainter-to-Prepare-a-cascades-Image/ta-p/1809841

Comment: Thank you, but that tutorial doesn't show all the code - and the tutorial link: The source code for this sample can be downloaded from the BlackBerry® project on Github® here:  https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/QImageScratchPad, gets a 404 Not Found Error, unless I can find the source code for it somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah, it has been removed as those classes are deprecated now. Anyways, fortunately I have that sample code. I have uploaded here on below mentioned link. You can download it from there.

http://www.filedropper.com/qimagescratchpad

I haven't run on the device as I have a device with beta 3 OS. But you can get an idea from that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check to see if the QNetworkReply is redirecting you to the actual image.  If it is, you will receive a new QUrl what will be used to get a new request.  Check out the documentation for [QNetworkRequest::Attributes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkrequest.html#Attribute-enum)

```
void MyClass::saveImage(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    QUrl redirect = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
    if( redirect.isValid() ) {
        QNetworkRequest request(redirect);
        networkAccessManager_->get(request);
    }
    else {
        QByteArray imageData = reply->readAll();

        if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            qDebug() << "an error occured downloading the image";
            return;
        }

        qDebug() << imageData;
    }
}
```